# Which programming style is better? from an optimization perspective

Tags: c++

Having a large integer 32/64bit, I'm modifying several bit positions.

Style 1

```
Integer64 = Modify(Integer64);
```

Style 2

```
Modify(Integer64);
```

Style 3

```
Using the same style as the 1st, but inline function
```

- 1st) returns a 64bit modified
  value
- 2nd) a backup buffer is
  created and the original value is
  copied, too. the calculations are then
  stored into the original input values
  place
- 3rd) Modify is an inline
  function.

I also believe Style 2 is more descriptive to that particular step in the code.

Which is the best style to use from an execution perspective?

Comment: Do not try to optimize prematurely. Ever. And if you are serious about this, it's more important to see the assembly the compiler generates rather than the source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't pick a style from an optimization perspective. Pick the one that, when read by future maintainers, will most clearly indicate what's happening. Then if your program has performance problems you can profile and see if the method is causing problems, and if so then consider your options at that point.

Comment: Indeed.  Won't somebody think of the children??!

Comment: None of the options presented are difficult to read. Yes, it's not everything, but performance can matter. I see no reason to simply ignore performance as your reply seems to suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are good that it makes no difference at all.

With a modern compiler, marking the function as inline rarely has any noticeable effect on whether code for it will be generated inline or not. If the function in question is as short as you imply, it'll probably be generated inline whether you mark it as inline or not.

Once that happens, whether you copy it into a temporary and back out, or modify it in place, etc., is unlikely to make any real difference either. The compiler will analyze the data flow, and only copy it about as much as needed. Chances are pretty decent that either way it'll get loaded into a register, modified as needed, and stored back to the original location.

All of that assumes you turn the compiler's optimization on, of course. Some compilers do have intermediate optimization settings where functions are generated inline only if they're explicitly marked inline -- but, quite frankly, I rarely see much use for such settings (though you might -- they are sometimes useful with code that breaks when full optimization is turned on).

Answer (score 1):

To the extent I follow, your second method would not modify the argument unless you passed it by reference.

Using an inline function is probably your most efficient method, and is likely the version I would choose. However, there may be other considerations that depend on just exactly what you are doing with the integer.

Comment: Shifting bits here and there.